# Python pandas to_csv issue

Tags: python, pandas

I am running python program which takes csv data as string, need to sort it and return output as string

input= "Bet,Charle,Daniell,Ada,Eri\n17945,10091,10088,3907,10132\n2,12,13,48,11"

desired output = "Ada,Bet,Charle,Daniell,Eri\n3907,17945,10091,10088,10132\n48,2,12,13,11"

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

def sort_csv(input):
  str_data = StringIO(input)
  output_df = pd.read_csv(str_data, sep=",")
  output_df = output_df.sort_index(axis=1)
  output_df.to_csv(path_or_buf='temp.csv', index=False)
  data = open('temp.csv').read()
  return data
```

I am facing below error
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method

pandas package is upgraded, using python 3.4.
Any help?

Comment: May I ask why are you even using pandas for this? it's a huge overkill

Comment: How are you calling the sort_csv function on your string? Asking because when using sort_csv(input), your code actually works for me.

Comment: Any better idea instead of using pandas?, as pandas has good functions for sorting and converting, I have opted for pandas

Comment: Yes @sigma1510, now its working fine for me in pycharm IDE with python 3.7.2,, but not working for python 3.4 with plain python run . Also I am not even slicing the dataframe. Was curious about the error. Also looking for better way instead of pandas(as deepspace mentioned seems its overkill)

Comment: If you type python3 --version into the terminal, what version do you get? Sometimes when python2 and python3 are both installed, the terminal will default to python2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an implementation that avoids using `pandas`, and allows for the ability to sort by different columns. Once you break your input string into a list of lists, your specified sorting column (i.e. the list you want to use to sort from your list of lists) is sorted whilst keeping note of the original indices, which are then passed as the sorting key to the other lists. Afterwards, you simply re-join the string together:

```
x =  "Bet,Charle,Daniell,Ada,Eri\n17945,10091,10088,3907,10132\n2,12,13,48,11"

col_to_sort = 0

sublists = [i.split(',') for i in x.split()]

sorted_list = [[l[i] for i in sorted(range(len(sublists[col_to_sort])), key=lambda k: sublists[col_to_sort][k])] for l in sublists]

print(repr('\n'.join(','.join(k) for k in sorted_list)))
```

Yields:

```
'Ada,Bet,Charle,Daniell,Eri\n3907,17945,10091,10088,10132\n48,2,12,13,11'
```